# Net 6 Web app microservice, Generate database in production server

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I just finished creating a test API project with database code first.

The database I use is PostgreSQL 14.

On my PC I used these commands to generate the database:

```
add-migration AddStudentToDb

update-database
```

Everything goes well, it generates the database and the app works fine.

I want to publish this app on my server (OS : ubuntu 22, DB: PostgreSQL 14).

I use the Visual Studio 22 publish system to publish the application

[image: Publish]

Once the solution is published I move it to the server.

The same version of Net 6 SDK that I have on the development PC is installed on the server.

[image: .Net6 SDK version]

The connection string is correct,but I have a problem the database is not generated in the Prod PostgreSQL.

Do I have to give a specific command to generate the database?

I really don't know how to act in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `program.cs` to apply migrations on app startup `dataContext.Database.Migrate();` . You can find more info here [Tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/02/01/net-6-execute-ef-database-migrations-from-code-on-startup)